# How to read a file line by line in Chapel

Tags: chapel

I don't see an example of reading a file line-by-line in the Chapel [File I/O primer](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/primers/fileIO.html).  Suppose I have a csv `data.csv`

```
NAME,RANK,SERIAL_NUMBER
Bootsy Collins,Bassist,8ntNoThing
Chappie,Robot,3.14159
Orange,Flavor,54321
```

I'd like to read this in line by line and split along the way. Something like

```
 for line in file.lines {
    var (name, rank, serialNumber) = line.split(',')
```

What is the most compact way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lower down in the documentation](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/primers/fileIO.html#reading-and-printing-utf-8-lines), it gives the following example code (I pulled the first line from a previous code block):

```
var f = open(testfile, iomode.cwr);
var r = f.reader();
var line:string;
while( r.readline(line) ) {
   write("Read line: ", line);
}
r.close();
```

I've never written Chapel before, so assuming your code snippet is correct, I assume this would look like:

```
var f = open(testfile, iomode.cwr);
var r = f.reader();
var line:string;
while( r.readline(line) ) {
   var (name, rank, serialNumber) = line.split(',')
}
r.close();
```

Comment: One note, looks like you want `iomode.r` otherwise it over-writes your data file and the tuple `(name, rank,..)` appears to be illegal in chapel. Thanks